# Refactor 3 parent child category relation queries with whereHas or another type of query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have categories and channels table with a following relationship. A category hasMany channels. What I'm trying to do is get all channels that belong to a parents sub categories. I have one working attempt (Attempt 2 in controller) at this time and am wondering if I could make that into one query?

**Channel Categories**

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('slug');
$table->integer('parent_id')->default(null);
```

**Channels**

```php
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('slug');
$table->integer('category_id');
```

**Get All Channels By Category Slug Route**

```php
Route::get('/{channelCategory}', 'ChannelController@index');
```

**ChannelController**

```php
public function index($channelCategory)
{

         //Attempt 1. This works perfectly fine, but would like it to be in one query if possible
        /*if($channelCategory->parent_id === 0){
            $categories = ChannelCategory::where(['parent_id' => $channelCategory->id])->pluck('id');
            $channels = Channel::whereIn('category_id', $categories)->get();
        } else {
            $channels = $channelCategory->channels;
        }*/

         //Attempt 2 whereHas Query. 
         //The problem is that it gets all posts from all parent categories instead of just one.
        /*$channels = Channel::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($channelCategory) {
            $query->where('parent_id', $channelCategory->parent_id);
            $query->orWhere('parent_id', null);

         })->get(); */



    return view('channels.home', compact('channels'));
}
```

Maybe what I am trying to do isn't possible with a whereHas. Is it possible to do the second attempt in one query and if so how?

Comment: I'm asking me about your code, what contains `$channelCategory` ? it's an objet or just a string ? why `$channelCategory->id` ?

Comment: it's an object. So when I send a request to the route it automatically news up a `ChannelCategory  $channelCategory` in the index method on the controller.

Comment: Oh sorry. that should be `$channelCategory->slug`

Just looking at that I think it's a useless piece of code that I changed and was trying to use to figure out problems that I further deleted. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this by just eager loading the channels then mapping the category channels together:

```
$categories = ChannelCategory::with('channels')
                             ->where('parent_id', $channelCategory->id)
                             ->get();

return view('channels.home', [
    'channels' => $categories->flatMap->channels
]);
```

Pagination would likely need to be done manually using the [LengthAwarePaginator](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html) class:

```
$page = $request->get('page', 1);
$perPage = $request->get('perPage', 15);
$channels = $categories->flatMap->channels;
$items = $channels->forPage($page, $perPage);

$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($items, $channels->count(), $perPage, $page);
```

Getting the latest would involve sorting the collection and taking the limit desired:

```
$limit = $request->get('limit', 10);
$latest = collect($categories->flatMap->channels)->sortByDesc('created_at')->take($limit);
```

Comment: This is working, but isn't able to use latest() or paginate channels. Is there anyway that can be done?